# Adding insulation to a loft conversion & condensation build up concerns

Tags: insulation, attic, condensation

I just moved into a property and I want to get some insulation added to the existing loft conversion as it gets mighty cold up there. I've had a look via the eaves and there is about 8-10cm of space from the ceiling of the room to the roofing felt. Is this enough space to add any sort of insulation without concerns of condensation build up?

Here are some photos to help explain:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Are there any soffit and ridge/roof vents? There should be for air flow to keep the attic space from getting too hot in the summer (shortening the life span of roofing materials) and to allow it to dry out. So long as you leave roof for air to flow (roughly 1-2" (2-5cm)) you should be OK as far as condensation issues are concerned.

Comment: @FreeMan yes I believe we have soffits, at least our surveyor mentioned them in his report if that's clarification of their existence!

Comment: Oh, I'm very certain they _exist_, the question is if they are _ventilated_. This might be continuous perforations on vinyl/aluminum siding or holes cut out of wooden siding covered with some sort of mesh/grate to (hopefully) keep out bugs and other wildlife, while allowing air to flow. If you're not sure, take pics of the soffits (from a bit of a distance for a good overview, then as much of a closeup as you can safely get) and [edit] them into your question. Someone here will be able to identify ventilation if it exists.

Comment: Any chance you can draw a cross-section of the overall roof assembly? We can make some decent guesses but with a cross-section those guesses can turn in to a plan of action.